# How to assign value to a specific attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing an extend form function, in which I need to increment certain attributes including ones like `data-display="#display_student_1_gender"`.

There is no problem in finding the attribute but it fails (marked below) when I am trying to rename it. What gives?

The Javascript:

```
<script>
var counter = 0;
function moreFields(val1, val2, val3) {
    counter++;
    var newField = document.getElementById(val1).cloneNode(true);
    newField.id = '';
    newField.style.display = 'block';
    var newFields = newField.querySelectorAll('[name], [id], [for], [data-display]');
        for (var i=0;i<newFields.length;i++) {
            var theNames = newFields[i].name
            if (theNames)
                newFields[i].name = "data[" + val3 + "][" + counter + "][" + theNames + "]";
            var theNames2 = newFields[i].id;
            if (theNames2)
                newFields[i].id = theNames2 + counter;
            var theNames3 = newFields[i].htmlFor;
            if (theNames3)
                newFields[i].htmlFor = theNames3 + counter;
            var theNames4 = newFields[i].attr('data-display'); //line 14 Error
            if (theNames4)
                newFields[i].attr('data-display') = theNames4 + counter;    
        }           
    var insertHere = document.getElementById(val2);
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newField,insertHere);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with dom element(`newFields[i]`) references which does not hae method like `attr()`(I think you got in from some jQuery references - but since you have not tagged the question with jQuery, I'm assuming you are not using it).

You need to use getAttribute() and setAttribute() to get/set attribute values

```
var theNames4 = newFields[i].getAttribute('data-display');
newFields[i].setAttribute('data-display', theNames4 + counter)
```

or if you are using data api

```
var theNames4 = newFields[i].dataset.display;
newFields[i].dataset.display = theNames4 + counter
```

Comment: Need to convert to Number too btw.

Comment: @potatopeelings number?

Comment: I believe naming 4 attributes separately like this is repetitive. Would you be so kind to advise whether there is a faster way to do this? If its not too much for a short answer.

Comment: @AlvinMok since you are dealing with 4 different attributes and all of them has different values I think this is good

Comment: @ArunPJohny - wouldn't `theNames4 + counter` give you a string? So 0 would become 01, that would become 011...?

Comment: @potatopeelings Yes... I think the counter increment should happen in the for loop and instead of `theNames4 + counter` we will need to do a string replace like `theNames4.replace(/\d+$/, '') + counter`